# Why "colcon build" fails to build some of the Autoware.Auto packages?

Tags: ros, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Without using ADE

I am trying to install Autoware.Auto [without using ADE](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation-no-ade.html). I installed `ros-foxy-desktop` [via Debian packages](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html), i.e by typing `sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop` in terminal. I also installed all the dependencies as is written in the Installation document of Autoware.Auto.

The problem is that when I build the Autoware.Auto packages with `colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo` some packages fail. At the end I see such a message:

```
Summary: 94 packages finished [4min 53s]
  11 packages had stderr output: ament_acado autoware_auto_common lanelet2_global_planner mpc_controller ndt ndt_mapping_nodes ndt_nodes point_cloud_mapping rosapi spinnaker_camera_driver spinnaker_camera_nodes
```

To be more specific, here is the first stderr message:

```
--- stderr: autoware_auto_common                                                                                                                                                               
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:53 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_cpplint/cmake/ament_cmake_cpplintConfig.cmake

  but it set ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND to FALSE so package
  "ament_cmake_cpplint" is considered to be NOT FOUND.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /opt/ros/foxy/share/ament_cmake_uncrustify/cmake/ament_cmake_uncrustifyConfig.cmake

  but it set ament_cmake_uncrustify_FOUND to FALSE so package
  "ament_cmake_uncrustify" is considered to be NOT FOUND.


---
Finished <<< autoware_auto_common [23.8s]
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04.

##Inside ADE
I have to note that the same problem exists inside ADE. I use the [installation guide](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation-ade.html) and when I run build the project, I find similar errors.

```
Summary: 93 packages finished [2min 48s]
  12 packages had stderr output: ament_acado autoware_auto_common had_map_utils lanelet2_global_planner mpc_controller ndt ndt_mapping_nodes ndt_nodes point_cloud_mapping rosapi spinnaker_camera_driver spinnaker_camera_nodes
```

My question is that why I see the above stderr? Does it mean that I missed some dependencies? By the way, I installed all dependencies from Autoware.Auto documentation. I appreciate any suggestion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376842/why-%22colcon-build%22-fails-to-build-some-of-the-autoware.auto-packages?/) by [ashakeri](https://answers.ros.org/users/73650/ashakeri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpace121](https://answers.ros.org/users/51025/jpace121/) on 2021-04-24**:
Are cpplint and uncrustify installed?

**Comment by [ashakeri](https://answers.ros.org/users/73650/ashakeri/) on 2021-04-26**:
@jpace121 Yes they are installed but the same problem exist. I installed the cpplint via "pip install cpplint".

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2021-04-26**:
It's not actually failing though. It's a warning. Maybe just proceed with whatever you wanted to do and see if it works?

**Comment by [ashakeri](https://answers.ros.org/users/73650/ashakeri/) on 2021-05-03**:
@christophebedard The functionalities that I want is not working. I do everything according to [this documentation](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/behavior-planner-howto.html) but it does not work. According to your answer I think there should be something missing in the documentation. Now, I am trying to find a solution.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2021-05-03**:
I'd suggest you open a new question for that other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not actually failling.

this

```
Finished <<< autoware_auto_common [23.8s]
```

and this

```
Summary: 93 packages finished [2min 48s]
```

show that it built just fine. You're just getting a CMake warning. Getting `X packages had stderr output` is fairly normal.

If building had actually failed, you would be getting different messages, e.g.

```
Failed   <<< autoware_auto_common [1.23s]
```

and

```
Summary: X packages finished [1.23s]
  1 package failed: autoware_auto_common
```

Seems like the warnings were fixed recently: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/merge_requests/926/diffs

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2021-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashakeri](https://answers.ros.org/users/73650/ashakeri/) on 2021-05-03**:
Thanks for the feedback. So I conclude that the problems that I have are not related to building the packages. For example one of the problems is that when I run the `ros2 launch autoware_auto_launch autoware_auto_visualization.launch.py` command, I get this error: `Package 'autoware_auto_launch' not found`.

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2021-05-03**:
at least not related to the warning you get when building `autoware_auto_common`